# Need an xpath that finds all the elements of a particular type before the first occurence of a certain element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I need an xpath that fetches all the elements of a particular element type, say input, that occurs before the first occurrence of another element. the problem is, there is no proper hierarchy between the targeted elements and the 'another element'. and there can be any number of 'another element' present in the html.

i tried using the `'following'` axes and it works if there is only one 'another element'. but if there are many it doesn't work

```
<a>
    <b>
        <input>zyx</input>
        <div>abc</div>
        <span>def</span>
        <input>ghi</input>
    </b>
    <c>
        <div class="SameAttribute">Test</div>
        <input>jkl</input>
        <div>mno</div>
    </c>
    <d>
        <div class="SameAttribute">Test</div>
        <input>pqr</input>
        <div>stu</div>
    </d>
</a>
```

as per the html structure above, i want only the `input` elements that are within the `<b>` tag. the xpath needs to ignore the `input` elements that are within `<c>` and `<d>` tags
Tried this

```
.//*[self::input][following::div[@class = 'SameAttribute']]
```

but it picks the elements from both `<b>` and `<c>` tags.

When i try this, nothing gets selected

```
.//*[self::input][following::(div[@class = 'SameAttribute'])[1]]
```

I cannot write xpaths containing any of the tags `<b>`, `<c>`, `<d>` due to other constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want only the input elements that are within the `<b>` tag. the xpath
>   needs to ignore the input elements that are within `<c>` and `<d>` tags

**Use**:

```
//b//input
```

> I need an xpath that fetches all the elements of a particular element
>   type, say input, that occurs before the first occurrence of another
>   element. the problem is, there is no proper hierarchy between the
>   targeted elements and the 'another element'. and there can be any
>   number of 'another element' present in the html.

This is not equivalent to the first requirement quoted above.

You don't specify what is mean't by "another element" but combining the two quoted requirements, and the provided source xml document, one can logically conclude that "another element" here means any following sibling of the element `/a/b[1]`

These will be selected by:

```
(//b)[1]//input
```

or for the provided xml document just:

```
/a/b[1]//input
```

If the document had more than one `/a/b` elements and you wanted to get the `input` descendants of only these `/a/b/` elements that precede any `/a/{X}` elements, where `{X}` is a name different from `b`, use:

```
/a/b[not(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::b)])]//input
```

Finally, in the most general case, if you want to select the `input` descendants of only such `b` elements that come **before* any other (`non-b`) element (excluding the top element -- if the top element is a `b` then any `input` descendant of the top element satisfies the requirement, here is one XPath expression that selects these:

```
/*//b[not(ancestor::*[not(self::b) and parent::*]) 
    and not(preceding::*[not(self::b)])]
      //input
```

Here we use the fact that if an element `x` is before (in document order) an element `y`, then `x` is either an ancestor of `y` (belongs to its`ancestor::*` axis) or is a preceding element (belongs to its `preceding::*` axis)

**XSLT-based verification**:

This transformation evaluates all 5 XPath expressions and outputs the selected nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//b//input"/>
    ==================================
    <xsl:copy-of select="(//b)[1]//input"/>
    ==================================
    <xsl:copy-of select="/a/b[1]//input"/>
    ==================================
    <xsl:copy-of select="/a/b[not(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::b)])]//input"/>
    ==================================
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*//b[not(ancestor::*[not(self::b) and parent::*])
        and not(preceding::*[not(self::b)])]
          //input"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the originally-provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <input>zyx</input>
        <div>abc</div>
        <span>def</span>
        <input>ghi</input>
    </b>
    <c>
        <div class="SameAttribute">Test</div>
        <input>jkl</input>
        <div>mno</div>
    </c>
    <d>
        <div class="SameAttribute">Test</div>
        <input>pqr</input>
        <div>stu</div>
    </d>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is selected when evaluating each expression**:

```
<input>zyx</input>
<input>ghi</input>
    ==================================
    <input>zyx</input>
<input>ghi</input>
    ==================================
    <input>zyx</input>
<input>ghi</input>
    ==================================
    <input>zyx</input>
<input>ghi</input>
    ==================================
    <input>zyx</input>
<input>ghi</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath

This is for indexing all input (please change count number for other) :

```
(.//*[self::input][following::div[@class = 'SameAttribute']])[1]
```

This is for simple way, `input` between tag `<b>` :

```
//b//input
```

Comment: the first xpath gives only the first `input` element but i want all the input elements within `<b>` .  the second xpath, cannot be used as i cannot write an xpath using any of the tags

Comment: Why can your xpath not contain the tag `<b>`?  There is no reliable way to get all children under a specific node if you cannot somehow identify the specific node you want to use.

Comment: @user-10132413 please post you real html

Answer (score 0):

One Xpath that would seem to meet your criteria is:

```
//input[not(preceding-sibling::*[contains(@class,'SameAttribute')])]
```

This will find all input elements that do not have a preceding sibling that has a class attribute that contains the class SameAttribute.

Comment: This illustrates the problem that we have with so many XPath questions: we're given one example document, and we have no idea which features of that document will also be present in other documents to which the expression is applied. Of course, if everything in the input document is fixed, then you don't need to search the document at all, you already know the answer.

Comment: I agree completely

Answer (score 0):

The way you've described the problem, the simplest solution is `//b/*`. Alternatively, if you want all the elements with the same parent as the first `input` element, you might want `(//input)[1]/following-sibling::*`.

You certainly don't want the `following` axis here: read up on the difference between `following` and `following-sibling`.

Your expression `//*[self::input]` is a very convoluted way of saying `//input`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the reason i had used it that way is that the expression has to handle multiple tags in the real time. it will be like `//*[self::input or self::select or self::textarea]`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the combination of `preceding` and `ancestor` axes to arrive at the solution. following is the xpath that worked for me

`(.//div[@class='SameAttribute'])[1]/preceding::*[self::input][ancestor::a]`

Comment: There is no way we could have got to this answer based on your question.  Where have the `<select>` and `<textarea>` tags come from?  It's only now after reading this answer that I really understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Those two tags are based on the actual html page that i'm working with. i updated  the answer.